# Run statements conditional

Tags: r

I would like to only run a statement under a certain condition. The issue is, that the statement should be a loop (or if condition etc.).
Example:

```
X<-TRUE

if(X){
"for(i in 1:4){
a<-i"
}else{
a<-5
}

print(a)

if(X){
"}"
}
```

The parts in `" "` here should only be run if `X==TRUE`. I have tried using the `eval()`-function, but it is not made for that. Can this be done in R?

Comment: `if(isTRUE(X)) {`

Comment: I don't understand why you neet the quotes. You can do somenthing like this ```if(X){
  for(i in 1:4){
a<-i
print(a)

  }
}else{
  a<-5
  print(a)
  
}
```

Comment: Yes, for this short case that makes sense of course but my `print(a)` is really a few hundred lines of code, that I do not want to repeat.

Comment: One way to do it then would be to put the main code in a function, but in my case there is also reasons to avoid that. (In addition to me currently wanting to do this, this is a general question, because I feel like it should be possible. If so I cannot find it, so this might also be interesting to others.)

Comment: Just create the functions, there is no way this is readable code, worst-case type more, space is cheap, errors are expensive

Comment: @Hope why are there reasons to avoid functions?

Comment: @CaptainHat there are two reasons: a) the code is supposed to modify many variables I want to use after the loop. I know I could use assign` to outside environment, but I don't want to forget any part. b) My for-loop is actually a nested parallelized foreach-loop, where I want to run examples as a simpler version, check variables, and debug things. I have to check over small things often so I'm looking for a way to turn of the "complicated stuff"

Comment: Also I'm not sure if the assign variant will work in combination with parallelization. Moreover there were other occasions where I thought "I wish I could just do this...."

Answer (score 0):

### Put `print(a)` in a function and use `lapply()`

(Or forgo `lapply` if your function can handle vector input)

Like this

```r
### This function could be anything
a_function_you_made <- function(x) print(x)

X <- TRUE

### If X, apply the function to every value in 1:4
if(X){
  # a_function_you_made(1:4) # << this will work if your function iterates over a vector (true for print)())
  lapply(as.list(1:4), a_function_you_made)# << storing inputs in a list is more generalisable
### Otherwise just run the function with value five
}else{
  a_function_you_made(5)
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- If your function iterates over a vector, you won't need to use `lapply`. This is true for print, so in the above example you could just run `a_function_you_made(1:4)`
- I've used `print` for consistency with your code, but it's a bad function for demonstrating `lapply`, because it's used for its side effects, but silently returns its input, which means `lapply` prints every value and then returns `as.list(1:4)`.

Comment: As a super-generalised rule-of-thumb: It's good to avoid loops in R where you can. They can be computationally expensive in ways that functions like `lapply` are designed to avoid.